# npm: cannot find module semver error while using npm command in linux ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, node-modules

When I use npm, I get this error. Every npm command ends up showing the following error (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall npm ?

Comment: Try `npm i semver` to install `semver` as it seems to be looking for it but it's not installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply reinstalled all Node.js versions and the error is gone!

Edit: The error caused by using yarn and npm simultaneously.
By removing one of them the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you run an npm command to start your code, one of the things your code will do is to fetch the module from the `require('')` line in your code. However the issue is, it's fetching a module named `semver` but it can't find it. It likely means it isn't installed. Try running `npm install semver`